# Write text to file in columns

Tags: python, output

As an attorney I am a total newbie in programimg. As an enthusiastic newbie, I learn a lot. (what are variables, ect.) ).

So I'm working a lot with `dir()` and I'm looking into results. It would by nicer if I could see the output in one or more columns. So I want to write my first program which write for example `dir(sys)` in a output file in columns.

So far I've got this:

```
textfile = open('output.txt','w')
syslist = dir(sys)

for x in syslist:
    print(x)
```

The output on display is exactly what I want, but when I use the `.write` like:

```
textfile = open('output.txt','w')
syslist = dir(sys)

for x in syslist:
    textfile.write(x)

textfile.close()
```

The text is in lines.

Can anyone pleaase help me, how to write the output of `dir(sys)` to a file in columns?

If I can ask you, please write the easysiet way, because I really have to look almost after for every word you write in documentation. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by columns? Give an example of what you want the output file to look like.

Comment: You ... probably want pretty printing.  `from pprint import pprint`, then `pprint(variable)`, or `pprint(dir(variable))` to get much cleaner, readable breakdowns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Python!

The following code will give you a tab-separated list in three columns, but it won't justify the output for you. It's not fully optimized so it should be easier to understand, and I've commented the portions that were added.

```
textfile = open('output.txt','w')
syslist = dir(sys)

MAX_COLUMNS = 3 # Maximum number of columns to print
colcount = 0    # Track the column number

for x in syslist:
    # First thing we do is add one to the column count when
    # starting the loop. Since we're doing some math on it below
    # we want to make sure we don't divide by zero.
    colcount += 1

    textfile.write(x)

    # After each entry, add a tab character ("\t")
    textfile.write("\t")

    # Now, check the column count against the MAX_COLUMNS. We
    # use a modulus operator (%) to get the remainder after dividing;
    # any number divisible by 3 in our example will return '0'
    # via modulus.
    if colcount % MAX_COLUMNS == 0:
        # Now write out a new-line ("\n") to move to the next line.
        textfile.write("\n")

textfile.close()
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

`print` adds a newline after the string printed by default, file.write doesn't. You can do:

```
for x in syslist: textfile.write("%s\n" % x)
```

...to add newlines as you're appending. Or:

```
for x in syslist: textfile.write("%s\t" % x)
```

...for tabs in between.

I hope this is clear for you "prima facie" ;)

Answer (score 2):

The other answers seem to be correct if they guess that you're trying to add newlines that .write doesn't provide. But since you're new to programming, I'll point out some good practices in python that end up making your life easier:

```
with open('output.txt', 'w') as textfile:
  for x in dir(sys):
    textfile.write('{f}\n'.format(f=x))
```

The 'with' uses 'open' as a context manager.  It automatically closes the file it opens, and allows you to see at a quick glance where the file is open.  Only keep things inside the context manager that need to be there. Also, using .format is often encouraged.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused by your question, but I imagine the answer is as simple as adding in tabs. So change `textfile.write(x)` to `textfile.write(x + "\t")`, no? You can adjust the number of tabs based on the size of the data.

I'm editing my answer.

Note that dir(sys) gives you an array of string values. These string values do not have any formatting. The `print x` command adds a newline character by default, which is why you are seeing them each on their own line. However, write does not. So when you call write, you need to add in any necessary formatting. If you want it to look identical to the output of `print`, you need to add in `write(x + "\n")` to get those newline characters that print was automatically including.